# Why isn't `history -a` working?

Tags: terminal, bash, history

I am working under OS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks), using Terminal, which reports that it is GNU bash, version 3.2.51(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin13)

I noticed some weird issues where history was not working properly: `history -a` and `history -a filename.txt` don't do *anything*.  `history` shows the history I would expect.  This breaks my .bashrc synchronization of history across terminals.

I started to investigate by manually changing bash HIST variables.  Here is how I am able to reproduce my problem under somewhat controlled conditions:

1. I disabled my .bashrc
2. I opened a new terminal window and cleared the history

   ```
   history -c
   ```
3. I confirmed that my PROMPT_COMMAND is back to normal/default:

   ```
   echo $PROMPT_COMMAND
   ```

   This returns: update_terminal_cwd;
4. I manually set the relevant HIST variables:

   ```
   export HISTFILE="/Users/rsage/temp_history.txt"
   export HISTSIZE=20000
   export HISTFILESIZE=20000
   ```
5. I confirm my test history files are deleted:

   ```
   ls *history*.txt # To make sure I know what I'm about to delete
   rm *history*.txt
   ```
6. I attempt to save the history using `history -a` with no luck

   ```
   history -a
   history -a history_a.txt
   ls -ltr ; date
   ```

   This latter shows no history files:

   ```
   ...
   drwx------+ 40 rsage  staff   1360 Dec 20 14:16 Desktop
   drwxr-xr-x   4 rsage  staff    136 Dec 20 18:48 webApps
   drwxr-xr-x   8 rsage  staff    272 Dec 22 09:11 code
   drwxr-xr-x  17 rsage  staff    578 Dec 22 09:26 stuff
   ```

   Sun Dec 22 10:17:50 PST 2013
7. ...but I stumbled across the `history -w` command (I know it overwrites the file, which is fine with my nominal bashrc) and this seems to work fine:

   ```
   history -w
   history -w history_w.txt
   ls -ltr ; date
   ```

   which produces the expected results:

   ```
   ...
   drwx------+ 40 rsage  staff   1360 Dec 20 14:16 Desktop
   drwxr-xr-x   4 rsage  staff    136 Dec 20 18:48 webApps
   drwxr-xr-x   8 rsage  staff    272 Dec 22 09:11 code
   drwxr-xr-x  17 rsage  staff    578 Dec 22 09:26 stuff
   -rw-------   1 rsage  staff    461 Dec 22 10:19 temp_history.txt
   -rw-------   1 rsage  staff    494 Dec 22 10:19 history_w.txt
   ```

One last note.  It occurred to me that my sizes might be too large, so I just tried 200 and no change to behavior (the thirties are the history output numbers):

```
34  export HISTFILESIZE=200
35  export HISTSIZE=200
36  history -a
37  history -a history_a.txt
38  ls -ltr ; date
```

The ls outputs show no new files.

Comment: I just repeated the experiment on another computer with OS X 10.8.5, GNU bash, version 3.2.48(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin12).  I guess it's not Mavericks...

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the same odd behavior, checked permissions, and sure enough, both the "World" and "System" had explicit permissions set to read AND write my .bash_history file, but I (the owner) had no permissions to that file at all!

I just forced "World" to "No Access" and gave myself and system r/w access and voila, everything is working the way it should.

Answer (score 1):

For El Capitan (10.11.6) I ran into `history -a` not working - https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473581/135943

Copying my self-answer from there:

---

It seems this is something Apple-specific.  (I'm using Mac OS 10.11.6 El Capitan.)

My `HISTFILE` value is the immediate cause:

```
[512] $ echo $HISTFILE
/Users/Wildcard/.bash_sessions/8BC6B122-0D74-445B-B6A0-7D4D446598CB.historynew
```

But since I don't set that variable, where is it being set?

Aha, it's in `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal`.  And from the comments there, it looks like I only ran into this because I tried `history -a` by itself, without ever setting `shopt -s histappend`.  They've coded it so that if you turn on histappend, or set the HISTTIMEFORMAT variable, they skip the session resume support code.

Here's the inline documentation for that section:

```
# Resume Support: Save/Restore Shell State
#
# Terminal assigns each terminal session a unique identifier and
# communicates it via the TERM_SESSION_ID environment variable so that
# programs running in a terminal can save/restore application-specific
# state when quitting and restarting Terminal with Resume enabled.
#
# The following code defines a shell save/restore mechanism. Users can
# add custom state by defining a shell_session_save_user_state function
# that writes restoration commands to the session file at exit. e.g.,
# to save a variable:
#
#   shell_session_save_user_state() { echo MY_VAR="'$MY_VAR'" >> "$SHELL_SESSION_FILE"; }
#
# During shell startup the session file is executed. Old files are
# periodically deleted.
#
# The default behavior arranges to save and restore the bash command
# history independently for each restored terminal session. It also
# merges commands into the global history for new sessions. Because
# of this it is recommended that you set HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE to
# larger values.
#
# You may disable this behavior and share a single history by setting
# SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 0. There are some common user customizations
# that arrange to share new commands among running shells by
# manipulating the history at each prompt, and they typically include
# 'shopt -s histappend'; therefore, if the histappend shell option is
# enabled, per-session history is disabled by default. You may
# explicitly enable it by setting SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY to 1.
#
# The implementation of per-session command histories in combination
# with a shared global command history is incompatible with the
# HISTTIMEFORMAT variable--the timestamps are applied inconsistently
# to different parts of the history; therefore, if HISTTIMEFORMAT is
# defined, per-session history is disabled by default.
#
# Note that this uses PROMPT_COMMAND to enable per-session history
# the first time for each new session. If you customize PROMPT_COMMAND
# be sure to include the previous value. e.g.,
#
#   PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+$PROMPT_COMMAND; }your_code_here"
#
# Otherwise, the per-session history won't take effect until the first
# restore.
#
# The save/restore mechanism is disabled if the following file exists:
#
#   ~/.bash_sessions_disable
```

Comment: +1 this seems to be the most relevant solution, just set SHELL_SESSION_HISTORY as you would like

Answer (score 0):

I have two answers - why the procedure does not work and why my original problem happened.

## history -a issue

In addition to the procedure for repeating this above, I started systematically building my .bashrc up from the ground up.  Pretty quickly I determined that it's the `history -c` that wrecks everything.

If you do the procedure with or without the `history -c`, you find that `history -a` works if `history -c` has not been called in the instance of bash and `history -a` fails if `history -c` has been called.

## solution to original problem

That answer was not very satisfying - particularly since the issue is that my .bashrc formula relies on `history -c` as part of propagating history (the standard `export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` shown at [Preserve bash history in multiple terminal windows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1288/preserve-bash-history-in-multiple-terminal-windows) among other places).

Without fixing this above issue, it seems that the history propagation issue results from using a (relative) path in HISTFILE.  HISTFILE seems to want a filename with no path.  Thus, changing from `HISTFILE="~/.bash_history_shared"` to `HISTFILE=".bash_history_shared"` fixes the original problem.

That raises the obvious question if that would fix the first issue shown above.  It seems not to.  That being said, the fact that the  `export PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r; $PROMPT_COMMAND"` works seems to suggest that perhaps the bizarre to me behavior of `history -a` is not unusual...?